# Hourglass cursor as soon as app starts, before first window shown

Tags: c#, wpf, startup

Our application entry point is currently as follows (also described in terms of computational time required to perform each operation), in App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
       // 1) Lengthy config load, db reading, internal data structures creation

       // 2) [about 4 seconds later] create splashscreen (it needs some info from config before being shown)

       // 3) [1-2 more seconds here] display the main view

       // 4) base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that after you launch the program 3-4 seconds are needed before the user gets any feedback that something is going on: so, before considering to refactor our startup code we'd thought about changing the mouse cursor (from arrow to hourglass) as soon as the application starts. The problem with this approach is that techniques like `Mouse.OverrideCursor` etc. seem to be working only when you already have a WPF Window, while our first window will be created after several seconds. Apart from changing the cursor globally (which we already tested but that requires P/Invoke and messing around with a registry, not something you'll want to do in this scenario) is there any other way to quickly solve the issue?

The proposed duplicate portraits correctly my scenario, but ultimately doesn't provide a valid answer. As you can see, the best answer in that topic, written by "Kevin DiTraglia", suggests the same thing which I already tried over and over, to no avail.

Comment: In Winforms you could use:
`Application.UseWaitCursor = true;` or 
`Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;`, but seems this isn't as simple in WPF as the cursor is linked to a Window instance (as you've discovered).

Comment: @PatrickHofman I've just seen the reply you kindly provided me. It correctly portraits my scenario, but ultimately doesn't provide a valid answer. As you can see, the best answer in that topic, written by "Kevin DiTraglia", suggests the same thing which I already tried over and over, to no avail. Maybe you could re-open my question? thanks

Comment: Did you try to do `base.Startup()` first?

Comment: Just use a Splashscreen, do *not* let it wait for slow config loading.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, to no avail unfortunately. I have even tried removing it altogether

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, that would solve the problem, but as stated in the topic we're trying to work out a solution which doesn't require us to refactor existing code. Of course if this REALLY can't be done that would be the only solution I guess..

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing all synchronous startup method calls asynchronous where possible.

Comment: yeah, as i told @HansPassant that would solve the problem, but as stated in the topic we're trying to work out a solution which doesn't require us to refactor existing code. Of course if this REALLY can't be done that would be the only solution I guess